# Managing multiple test groups in single testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

In my `Java` based project managed by `testNG` I have a large variety of tests, each test can belong to several groups. Let's say the groups are "Sanity", "Regression", "UI", "API", "Integration", "Module1", "Module2", "Module3" etc.
E.g. `@Test(priority = 7 ,groups= {"Sanity", "Regression", "UI", "Partners"}, description= "Create new partner")`
I want to be able to run my tests on `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Edge` browsers.
I know I can create separate test in `testng.xml` for each specific combination or for each specific group e.g.

```
<test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="ChromeTests">  
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>  
    <classes>  
        <class name="tests.MainRunner">  
        </class>  
    </classes>  
</test>
```

to run all the tests in `Chrome` and I can use

```
<test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="Sanity Tests">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name = "Sanity">
            </include>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.MainRunner">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

to run "Sanity" related tests and I can use

```
 <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="ChromeTests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name = "Sanity">
            </include>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.MainRunner">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

to run "Sanity" tests on "Chrome".
But I have 3 browsers and let's say 10 test groups.
I do not think I have to define 30 tests in `testng.xml` to cover all the possible combinations I have.
Also, how can I invoke specific test in `testng.xml` from inside the `IntelliJ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your groups into a few separate **.xml** files - **Sanity.xml** & **Regression.xml** etc.
And then do the following:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression">

  <test name="Regression Suite">

    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="Regression"/>
      </run>
    </groups>

    <packages>
      <package name="com.auto.test.*"/>
    </packages>

  </test>

</suite>
```

Then you need to update your pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
          <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suites/${suite}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Then whenever you run your tests in Maven, you will have to pass the suite filename like this:

```
mvn clean test -Dsuite=Regression
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following issue implemented: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115242
It should provide the ability to run several groups separated with comma:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What 'Group' radio button and  'Suite' radio button should I select? How and where?

Comment: It's TestNG run/debug configuration options  in Run/Debug configurations.

Comment: Ah, now I understand you, thanks! This really helps and answers my last question but not the main question I asked.
By the way, can you please also tell me is it possible to set the Run configuration according to the tests I defined in my tesng.xml file?
Currently I see ability to set the run according to 1) all in package 2)Class 3)Method 4)Group 5)Suite 6)Pattern (I still do not know what this pattern is)